# How to select particular record one by one depending on condition?

Tags: sql-server-2008

As given in below image I am having two table I want to insert record in Table 2 and map LicenseID from Table 1. but I want to select LicenseID depending on ComapanyCount and Count of records in Table 2 for that LicenseID. Means I can Map LicenseID 9 With 5 records in Table 2 after 5 record it should give me next LicenseID that is 12 which I can map with 3 record in table 2.

So I am Not able to write Query for selecting Such LicenseID So please some One help me for this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear with the relation between table1 and table2. Below query should update the licenseID in table 2 as per the need.

```
create table #tmp1
(
LicenseID int,
CompanyWindowId int,
CompanyCount int
)
GO
create table #tmp2
(
LicensedCompanyID int identity,
CompanyWindowId int,
CompanyID int,
LicenseID int
)
GO
insert into #tmp1 values (9,9,5),(12,9,2)
insert into #tmp2 (CompanyWindowId,CompanyID) values (9,10),(10,12),(10,14),(10,15),(10,16),(10,17),(10,18)
SELECT * from #tmp2
declare @licenseID int
declare @count int=1
declare @count2 int=1
declare @recordcount int
declare @CompanyCount int
select @recordcount=count(1) from #tmp1
WHILE @count2<=@recordcount
BEGIN
    select @licenseID=LicenseID,@CompanyCount=CompanyCount FROM (select *, row_number() over (order by licenseID) RID from #tmp1)T where  RID=@count2
    SET @count=1
    WHILE @CompanyCount>=@count
    BEGIN
        SET ROWCOUNT 1
        UPDATE #tmp2 SET LicenseID=@LicenseID WHERE LicenseID IS NULL
        SET @count+=1
    END

    SET @count2+=1
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0
SELECT * from #tmp2

drop table #tmp1
drop table #tmp2
```